# Cakephp submit form from outside of controller

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

i want to give my users the option to login to my cakephp domain from my maindomain (which is not a cakephp application)

for this purpose i have created the following:

```
      <header>
        <h2 id="loginHeader">Login</h2>
    </header>
    <form id="bloglic-login" action="http://www.myCakeApplication.com/cake2/index.php/users/login" method="post" name="blogliclogin">
        <input id="UserEmail" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="data[User][username]" value="" >
        <input id="UserPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="data[User][password]" value=""/>
        <a class="forgot" href="http://system.bloglic.com/users/forgot_password">Forgot your password?</a>
        <button class="signup" id="button-signup" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</section>
```

Now as you can see this form should access my usersController and the action login with a post request.

However when i click submit i get a cakephp error saying the request has blackholed.

Now i think the reason for this is that my form is not following the cake convention. But how can i avoid this error and make my users able to login?

**im using Cakephp version 2.3. I am also using ACL to administrate my users**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blackhole is from the [Security Component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html).  To answer your question, read the "[Disabling Security Component for Specific Actions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#disabling-security-component-for-specific-actions)" section.

Or (I'm not sure), you might be able to submit from another site if you [disable CSRF protection](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#disabling-the-csrf-protection) (worth a try)

Comment: Assuming there are no conflicting `SecurityComponent::requireAuth()`, `SecurityComponent::requireSecure()`, `SecurityComponent::requireGet()`, etc, then using `SecurityComponent::$unlockedActions` should do it, this will not only disable the `CSRF` check, but also the [`POST` validation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#SecurityComponent::$validatePost) which is necessary too in order to let Non-CakePHP form data pass through.